# Read Excel using Active JDBC in java

Tags: activejdbc, javalite

Can I read Excel file using active jdbc in java? I have been using Eclipse as IDE for java. Is there any jar files for active jdbc? 
Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveJDBC is an ORM for database access. As such, it was not built to read Excel files. The latest version of ActiveJDBC can be pulled from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.javalite%7Cactivejdbc%7C1.4.13%7Cjar).

Answer (score 0):

As You haven't given us exactly what you are trying to do. I'm suggesting another solution.

I have written a basic Excel ORM tool for these purposes. It's currently in development, but if you are looking for a basic solution you can try it.
I think it will mostly cover your basic needs.

And, feel free to contribute :)

[Excel ORM GitHub Repository Link](https://github.com/semihunaldi/ExcelOrm)